# How local fulfillment app gets run in the Google Nest device

Tags: google-smart-home

I'm trying to voice control my smart TV via Google Nest device. I have made a local fulfillment app and uploaded two bundles both node and web to the action console. When I tried to debug through the chrome://inspect, the web version failed to connect to the TV after a successful discovery. When I tried to run `node bundle-node.js` in terminal, it threw `ReferenceError: smarthome is not defined`.

So I am wondering how Google Nest device utilize those two bundles? Which version gets to serve in the Google Nest device? I assume the node version gets to serve, while the web version is for debugging. If my assumption holds, how does the dependency to `smarthome` get resolved in the node env? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [test and debug](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/local#3_test_and_debug_your_app) section of the Local Fulfillment Guide as a starting point. A couple highlights based on your question:

- You need to upload your bundles to submit for production, but during testing you should self-host your local fulfillment and enter that value in the **Enter your testing URL** field.
- The Local Home SDK is only present on Home/Nest devices, so you cannot currently test or debug on your local machine. You have to load the code onto the device as described in the guide and use `chrome://inspect`.
- Use the `web` bundle when testing your integration today. This is the version that will be run on Home speakers and Nest displays.

Comment: Thank you @Devunwired, you enlightened me and help me to go further. Right now, I only have one issue, that is the local fulfillment app is run in https domain. When connecting to my device, it is forced to send a secure request, which leads to a failed connection. Any chance we can configure the app to run in a http domain?

Comment: Also just curious, if the node bundle is not used, do we need to upload the node bundle?